# How to use generic delegates in C#

Tags: c#, generics, delegates

**I have these classes:**

```
public interface IPerson
{
    string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Person : IPerson
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public interface IRoom
{
    List<Furniture> Furnitures { get; set; }
    List<Person> People { get; set; }
}

public class Room : IRoom
{
    public List<Furniture> Furnitures { get; set; }
    public List<Person> People { get; set; }
}

public enum Furniture
{
    Table,
    Chair
}
```

---

**And I have this extension method:**

```
public static void Assign<T>(this IRoom sender, Func<IRoom,ICollection<T>> property, T value)
{
    // How do I actually add a Chair to the List<Furniture>?

}
```

---

**And I want to use it like this:**

```
var room = new Room();
room.Assign(x => x.Furnitures, Furniture.Chair);
room.Assign(x => x.People, new Person() { Name = "Joe" });
```

But I have no idea how to add `T` to `ICollection<T>`.

Trying to learn generics and delegates. I know `room.Furnitures.Add(Furniture.Chair)` works better :)

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void Assign<T>(this IRoom room, Func<IRoom, ICollection<T>> collectionSelector, T itemToAdd)
{
    collectionSelector(room).Add(itemToAdd);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a `Func<IRoom,ICollection<T>>` here. This takes room as argument and returns `ICollection<T>`. `ICollection<T>` as a parameter is enough. Let's rewrite your code as following to make it work.

```
public static void Assign<T>(this IRoom sender, ICollection<T> collection, T value)
{
    collection.Add(value);
}
```

Then call it as

```
room.Assign(room.Furnitures, Furniture.Chair);
room.Assign(room.People, new Person() { Name = "Joe" });
```

If you're not satisfied with this approach and you need your own approach only then try the following

```
public static void Assign<T>(this IRoom sender, Func<IRoom, ICollection<T>> property, T value)
{
    property(sender).Add(value);
}
```

Then call it with your own syntax should work

```
room.Assign(x => x.Furnitures, Furniture.Chair);
room.Assign(x => x.People, new Person() { Name = "Joe" });
```

Note:Keep in mind you've not initialized your collections, this will result in `NullReferenceException`, so to get rid of it add a contructor in your `Room` class as follows

```
public Room()
{
    Furnitures = new List<Furniture>();
    People = new List<Person>();
}
```